# Block helper with ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to make a simple block helper but can't find any documentation for ember-cli on the subject

**UPDATED**

Here's the helper:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default function uiInput(options) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(
    '<div class="ui input">'
    + options.fn(this)
    + '</div>');
}
```

And in the template:

```
{{#ui-input}}
  TEST
{{/ui-input}}
```

And the output should be:

```
<div class="ui input">
  TEST
</div>
```

But the output I'm getting is:

```
TEST
<div class="ui input">
  undefined
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason it has to be a helper? It seems like what you're doing would be a better fit for a component.

Comment: Maybe but this is a simplified version of my real problem. Regardless, I think there are situations where a block helper is the answer and I'd like to know how to make one. Just updated the question with new details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Original answer (see below for the ember way)

I first want to try to explain what is happening here: Ember (currently 1.9.1) does not return rendered templates as strings any more for quite some time now when calling `options.fn` directly (despite all of the code samples out there that rely on this behavior). Instead, your content is rendering 'itself', meaning that it uses `options.data.view`'s `appendChild` function to put things where they belong. You can see this in action e.g. by following the `with` helper's code down to line 81 in [ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/binding.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.9.1/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/binding.js#L81). You can also find a previous discussion on this [in this thread](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/block-helper-renders-directly-to-view/1465/2).

So, what can you do about it? We need to create a custom view to take care of what we need. The following code works for me using ember-cli. In `app/helpers/ui-input`:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

var UiInputView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: ['ui', 'input']
});

export default function(options) {
    var view = options.data.view;
    var viewOptions = {
        shouldDisplayFunc: function() {return true;},
        template: options.fn,
        inverseTemplate: options.inverse,
        isEscaped: !options.hash.unescaped,
        templateData: options.data,
        templateHash: options.hash,
        helperName: 'block-helper'
    };
    var childView = view.createChildView(UiInputView, viewOptions);
    view.appendChild(childView);
}
```

Maybe not all the viewOptions are necessary...

I hope this helps.

#### Update: the ember way

When I came here to answer this question, I was stubbornly determined that I should be able to write my own helpers. Little did I know about the [`{{yield}}`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_use-with-ember-component) helper. The correct code would thus look like this:

Component:

```
// app/components/ui-input.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['ui', 'input']
});
```

Template:

```
{{!-- app/templates/components/ui-input.hbs --}}
{{yield}}
```

Usage:

```
{{#ui-input}}
    Test
{{/ui-input}}
```

Comment: Marking you as the correct answer for the detailed explanation. The real take away is that block helpers are no longer supported and a component should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for marking my answer as correct. I think you are also right by saying it is not really supported. They would have docs for this otherwise. I still find it frustrating, though, since I work with block helpers all the time on the server side and they exist in htmlbars, so why not making them extendable? https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/active/0002-block-params.md also suggests, that they should be in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on ember-cli 0.1.4. When i try your ui-style helper in block notation:

```
{{#ui-input}}
  TEST
{{/ui-input}}
```

i get a javascript error in the console saying this:

```
Assertion failed: registerBoundHelper-generated helpers do not support use with Handlebars blocks.
```

however, this works for me with a slight tweak to your helper:

helper:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default function uiInput(input) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(
    '<div class="ui input">'
    + input
    + '</div>');
}
```

template:

```
{{ui-input 'TEST'}}
```

getting this output:

```
<div class="ui input">
  TEST
</div>
```

Comment: This does work but I need the helper to be in block notation.