# Handlebar helper syntax in Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

In this post

[Iterating over basic “for” loop using Handlebars.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924452/handlebar-js-iterating-over-for-basic-loop)

An example of a 'repeat' helper is layed out.

helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('times', function(n, block) {
    var accum = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        accum += block.fn(i);
    return accum;
});
```

template

```
{{#times 10}}
    <span>{{this}}</span>
{{/times}}
```

I can't seem to write this out the 'CLI' way... can someone enlighten me?

First of all, it will be it's own helper file in `/helpers` , and it should have a dash so the resolver recognizes it. - so I wouldn't be registering it explicitly.

Default generated helper looks like this `helpers/repeat-times.js` (template should be the same...)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function repeatTimes(input) {
  return input;
}

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(repeatTimes);
```

so, no need to register, no need to set the name... I just can't find clear docs on the syntax.  :/ (I took 20 or so stabs at it...)

Or should I be making a component instead? as suggested here: [Block helper with ember-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573658/block-helper-with-ember-cli)

Comment: I recently answered a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28865208/908842

Answer (score 4):

@Kalman is right that you can't register a bound helper with block notation, so in this case I would recommend a component, which was [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28865208/908842%20'Kalman%20Reference') in the comment.

However, for those that might have found this question and still want to create a handlebars helper in ember-cli, you'll want to use the **makeBoundHelper** function.

For example, here's a **current-date** helper that I use:

```js
// app/helpers/current-date.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function() {
  return moment().format('LL'); // Using moments format 'LL'
});
```

Then, in your handlebars template, you can use this:

```
{{current-date}}
```

Which yields a date like **March 5, 2015**